# Success callback on .load() complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I run another function based on success of `.load`

I am doing the following to load a PHP file:

```
$( ".sidebar-size" ).load( "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/sidebar-short.php" );
```

I want to run another javascript function called `gaLinks` when the above `.load` is complete, in a similar way to using `.success` or `.complete`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, take a look in the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("element").load(url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
    //execute your functions here...
});
```

Also, if you want a global callback you can use [something like](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/):

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
     //...
});
```

[or](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/):

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can include a callback in the `.load()` call according to the documentation.

```
$( ".sidebar-size" ).load( "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/sidebar-short.php", data, function(responseText,textStatus,jqXHR ) { alert('foo'); } );
```

"foo" is alerted on the callback. You can also check the function variables to see if it was successful.

https://api.jquery.com/load/